# What A* variant include additional restriction

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, a-star, traveling-salesman

Usually conditions, you want go from A to B with the smallest cost, but each link beside the cost have some items you can buy/collect.

Not really pokemon player but using the theme to explain it better, you want go from your home to the gym and pick up at least one of each item around the road, following the shortest route.

[image]

I can solve the shortest path with A*. How can I include the aditional restriction, or should I use a different algorithm?

I was thinking on use a starting Cost, so when you find items you reduce the cost and when you travel you increase the cost. And try to get close to 0.

Other option I was considering is try to find what paths cover all items. And then use A* with that subset. But not sure what algorith can solve that.

Comment: @MooingDuck Can provide some example? link or docs are ok.

Comment: My idea was silly, it sort of works on the assumption that you usually pick them up within a few tries, and I think A* heuristics are required to underestimate, so adding is invalid. Ignore what I said.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, unless you can find an admissible heuristic that actually prioritizes correctly, A* is not even applicable to the problem. In fact, with a poorly chosen heuristic, A* is reduced to being a really slow BFS. Slow because it uses a priority queue instead of a simple queue, and slow because it wastes time computing the heuristic.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Normally you mark a node as visited, so that each node is visited only once. But for this problem, you need to keep track of the items found and the distance travelled. Thus each node may be visited multiple times, with different sets of items.

Using your example lets assign labels to the items

```
A for 200 poke balls
B for lure module
C for incense
D for egg
```

and to the nodes

```
S for the start node
T for the top node
M for the middle node
L for the lowest node
Z for the end node
```

Assume that all paths have equal cost, and the cost is 1.

The problem starts with `{S::0}`, meaning node S with no items and 0 distance. You then queue `{T:C:1}`, `{M:A:1}`, and `{L:BD:1}`.

From `{T:C:1}`, you queue `{S:C:2}`, `{M:BC:2}`, and `{Z:BCD:2}`.

When you pull `{S:C:2}` from the queue, you'll note that node T already has item C with distance 1, so you *don't* queue `{T:C:3}`. But you will queue `{M:AC:3}` and `{L:BCD:3}`.

Eventually you'll find `{Z:ABCD:n}`, where `n` is some distance.

Comment: BFS is _way_ slower than A*.